# Lookup from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, lookup

Ok, so I have the database of people.
Many people can be members of Many organisations.
I have this implimented with a table of Orgs a table of people and a table of membership.
And then a lookup listbox in Members for both
This is fine.

But some people are members of Sub-organisations.
So I have a table of Sub-organisation (1 org has many sub orgs)

Now some people are just members of an organisation without being members of any of it's suborgs.
some organisations have no suborgs.
ATM I implemented this by having the look up look up from both:

SELECT [Sub-Organisations].[Group Name], Organisations.[Organisation Name]
FROM Organisations, [Sub-Organisations];

But this only comes up with options to be part of a suborg.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT so.[Group Name], o.[Organisation Name]
FROM Organisations AS o
LEFT JOIN [Sub-Organisations] AS so
    so.[Organisation Name] = o.[Organisation Name]
    -- Or whatever your parent child relationship identifier is
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select [s].[Group Name], [o].[Organisation Name] 
FROM Orgs o
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubOrgs s ON [s].[Organisation Name] = [o].[Organisation Name] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Membership m
```